# Restart VMWare virtual machine remotely via CLI

Tags: command-line, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware

There is a persistent problem in a VMWare virtual machine I'm using - whether it's `PCoIP`, `VMWare BLAST`, or `Microsoft RDP` - I get some error relating to the display protocol. Currently, I have to open a service request each time and have them restart the VM.

I'd like to stop pestering them while they try to fix this issue (it's been going on for weeks).

I tried running TeamViewer on the VM, but that hasn't helped (the partner doesn't respond - but it seems that, at least, it does recognize that TeamViewer is running on the computer)

I'm hoping to connect without displaying the desktop, since that seemed to be the problem, and issue a restart command via some command line tool.

- I can't download the VMWare CLI (since they need to confirm my
  identity first, that will take a few days, and it's the weekend).
- I can't seem to find a way to use the RDP protocol through a command
  line interface, and I wouldn't know how to connect to a VM from a
  pool within the host server - Only times I ever used RDP, It was
  pretty straightforward - connect directly to the relevant computer.
- TeamViewer doesn't seem to have any kind of CLI.

The errors I get:

- Using PCoIP: "Unable to connect to desktop: there is no available gateway for the display protocol"
- Using VMWare Blast: "The display protocol for this desktop is currently not available"
- Using Microsoft RDP: "There was an unexpected RDP disconnection. Microsoft RDP error code = 2825"

When trying to connect using Powershell, my VMware credentials aren't accepted for the server, even when specifying same domain, username, and password. Trying to connect directly to the VM (using the IP I got from the TeamViewer logs) returns an error:

```
Remote desktop can't connect to the remote desktop for one of these reasons:

 1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
 2. The remote computer is turned off
 3. The remote computer is not available on the network
```

I tried ports `9997` and `4172` as per [these instructions](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018809), assuming the whole thing is already configured. Using other ports gives me another error without even attempting to connect ("This computer can't connect to the remote desktop")

Is there any way for me to issue a remote command to restart without having to use a display protocol?

Thank you!

Comment: PowerShell Remoting.

Comment: @Seth Never knew what the use for that one is. But I still have a problem: I have a server with a few VMs. Microsoft RDP won't let me connect to the server, even with the username, password, and domain I use on the VMWare client, And I can't find a way to connect directly to a VM in a pool.

Comment: You could also give PsExec from the SysInternals collection a shot. In most cases you will have to setup configuration beforehand. Especially if you have the Microsoft Firewall enabled as the connection has to be allowed. If you would actually include what error your're getting you might be able to get help for that. To directly connect to a VM use the IP/DNS name of that server (assuming they're accessible from your client) and yes your VMware credentials might not allow logon. You could also use the VMware console and use their implementation of "remote view" for the VM.

Comment: @Seth thank you for your help :) I've added more information. I think If I can only find out how to connect to the VM without VMWare horizon, I could google around (which is what I always do first, A LOT) and find the cmdlets to do the rest. But I couldn't find anything about the whole server-pool thing. According to VMWare, I need 2 ports: for the server and for the VM inside the server. I just don't know how to connect to a VM through a server or whatever these are... I'm not familiar with this technology and I can't seem to find the answers on google...

Comment: @Seth oh, and as for the console, can't download that either due to that... policy I'm so tempted to call by some very bad works